# Plotting strings in a list as datapoints in a linegraph

Tags: python, string, list, matplotlib, plot

I have a list of lists as so:

```
lsofls = [0,0,0,0,0],["a",0,0,0,0],[0,"a",0,0,0],["b","a",0,0,0],["b",0,"a",0,0],["b",0,0,"a",0],[0,"b",0,"a",0],["c","b",0,"a",0],["c",0,"b","a",0],[0,"c","b","a",0],["d","c","b","a",0], ["d","c","b",0,"a"],["d","c","b",0,0],["d","c",0,"b",0]
```

And I wish to plot this, whereby each string in each list acts as its own datapoint. Each list in the list of lists is a point in time starting at t0 at the zeroth list. Each element in a list within the list of lists is a point in the sequence. I struggle to explain what I mean, but by printing the list of lists with each list as a new line it becomes clearer:

```
for s in lsofls:
    print(s)
```

This gives:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
['a', 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 'a', 0, 0, 0]
['b', 'a', 0, 0, 0]
['b', 0, 'a', 0, 0]
['b', 0, 0, 'a', 0]
[0, 'b', 0, 'a', 0]
['c', 'b', 0, 'a', 0]
['c', 0, 'b', 'a', 0]
[0, 'c', 'b', 'a', 0]
['d', 'c', 'b', 'a', 0]
['d', 'c', 'b', 0, 'a']
['d', 'c', 'b', 0, 0]
['d', 'c', 0, 'b', 0]
```

I essentially want to rotate this output 90 degrees anticlockwise, as a linegraph.

I am unsure how to do this, as I usually plot using integers.

I hope I am being clear enough, I am unsure how to phrase the question.

EDIT:
The solution provided by @ce.teuf is very close to what I need. However I need the string to be able to rejoin at position 1 in the graph. SO if you look at this list here:

```
lsofls = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ['a', 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 'a', 0, 0, 0], ['b', 'a', 0, 0, 0], ['b', 0, 'a', 0, 0], ['b', 0, 0, 'a', 0], [0, 'b', 0, 'a', 0], ['c', 'b', 0, 'a', 0], ['c', 0, 'b', 'a', 0], [0, 'c', 'b', 'a', 0], ['d', 'c', 'b', 'a', 0], ['d', 'c', 'b', 0, 'a'], ['d', 'c', 'b', 0, 0], ['d', 'c', 0, 'b', 0], ['d', 'c', 0, 0, 'b'], ['d', 0, 'c', 0, 'b'], [0, 'd', 'c', 0, 'b'], ['a', 'd', 'c', 0, 'b']

for s in lsofls:
    print(s)
```

So I need a way for each string to rejoin in the graph if that makes sense.

Comment: what do you expect?

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy essentially :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

z = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
['a', 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 'a', 0, 0, 0],
['b', 'a', 0, 0, 0],
['b', 0, 'a', 0, 0],
['b', 0, 0, 'a', 0],
[0, 'b', 0, 'a', 0],
['c', 'b', 0, 'a', 0],
['c', 0, 'b', 'a', 0],
[0, 'c', 'b', 'a', 0],
['d', 'c', 'b', 'a', 0],
['d', 'c', 'b', 0, 'a'],
['d', 'c', 'b', 0, 0],
['d', 'c', 0, 'b', 0]]

flat_list = [item for sublist in z for item in sublist]
series = list(set(flat_list))[1:]
y_len = len(z[0])

z2 = np.rot90(z)

for s in series:
    z3 = np.argwhere(z2== s)
    z3[:, 0] = (z3[:, 0] - y_len) * -1
    y, x = z3[:, 0], z3[:, 1]
    plt.plot(np.sort(x[::-1]), y[::-1])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is very close to what I need. For the code I am going to use this for the once a string has left the sequence it can rejoin at the start. The code you have given doesnt let the string to rejoin at position 1 in the graph again. I'll add an edit to the original code to let you know what I mean

Comment: Do you need all series "a", "b", "c" and "d" start at the origin (1,1) ?

Comment: No they start at different 'times' (by times i mean the x axis). But they all start at 1 on the y axis